# Unit testing methods which update UI elements in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I am trying to write unit tests for my existing code. 
I have 3 methods.

```
func methodOne() {
    // code
    methodTwo()
}

func methodTwo() {
    // code
    methodThree()
}

func methodThree() {
    // code
    // update UI element
}
```

What's the ideal way to unit test such methods. While unit testing `methodTwo()` it calls `methodThree()` as the UI elements are not loaded they have `nil` value when `methodThree()` is called. How to unit test methods which involve UI elements. I don't want to test if the UI element is loaded properly, I just want to test the code in `methodTwo()` and `methodThree()`. Is there a way to bypass UI elements related code. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried UI tests?

Comment: Then I won't be able to test `methodTwo()`. I don't want to test any UI related code here. I just want to test the code in `methodTwo()` and `methodThree()`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to separate the code you want to test from your UI as much as you can. This could be done by putting the `//code` part of `methodTwo` into its own function (ie `methodFour`) and calling it from `methodTwo`. Then your code would look like this:

```swift
func methodTwo() {
     methodFour()
     methodThree()
}

func testMethodFour() {
     methodFour()
     // check assumptions
}

func methodFour() {
     // code that you originally had in methodTwo before methodThree
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi [@Pradeep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11373446/pradeep) , welcome to StackOverflow.

From the way you describe the failures you are experiencing I'm guessing your methods are `@IBOutlet`s in a `UIViewController`, it that correct?

If that's the case, you can make the tests initialize the `UIViewController` view by doing something like this *before* calling the methods that depend on the view being available:

```
_ = viewControllerUnderTest.view
```

or

```
viewControllerUnderTest.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: false)
```

[This](https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-testing-view-controllers-swift/) is a decent post to learn more about the gotchas of testing `UIViewController`s, [this](https://albertodebortoli.com/2018/03/12/easy-view-controller-unit-testing/) has a more advanced approach that could help you if you end up writing a lot of tests with dependencies on the view like you described.

I would encourage you, though, to keep as much business logic code as you can aways from `UIViewController`s and `UIView`s. The lifecycle of these classes makes them a bit trickier to test, and the simplest you can make something to test the better.

Write all your business logic in dedicated `class`es and `struct`s, they will be simpler to test if they don't subclass other types. Use `UIViewController`s only as glue code to show data to the user and forward their inputs to your business logic, so that you'll have to write only a few straightforward tests. Keep the `UIView`s [humble](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html#HumbleView), with only logic to configure them.

(*If my `UIViewController` guess was wrong, please add more details and we'll figure out a way to get your tests to not crash.*)

Comment: I am using mocking as a workaround for now. I'll check your suggestion later. Thank you for your response.